# FullCalendar - What level of events rendering performance should I expect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, browser, fullcalendar

I am rendering 100 events in FullCalendar using `$('#CalendarPlugin').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {} );` being called 100 times in a loop.

The browser performance I'm seeing on my computer *(Core2 6600 @ 2.4GHz with 4GB RAM)*

- **Chrome**: 3 seconds
- **Firefox**: 6 seconds
- **IE9**: 6 seconds

Is this an expected level of performance? Is there a faster way to load and render events?

Once they've been added to FullCalendar, moving between months and re-rendering it much faster. It's just the initial loading of them using `renderEvent` that's slow.

Comment: Yes definately use a server side ajax to get events- I have a db with hundreds of thousands of events for the past 10 years. I have a complex feed where people can chosoe what they want to see but still- at most i wont disaplay more than 50 events per month tops! And its quick. but the db and page are on the same server- dont split them!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The developer was working on performance enhancements for the 1.4.4 version, but hitting the plugin 100 times in a loop is still hefty.

One technique you could try to improve performance is to use an object in `addEventSource` as this waits and renders altogether I believe:

```
 $("#calendar").fullCalendar("addEventSource", msg.items);
```

Comment: @Gary-Green I've changed to code to create an array of the 100 events, then to assign that using `addEventSource` and I'm seeing a big performance increase. Looks like there's much less overhead this way.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to fetch all events in a certain period at once, look at the api

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/

Your performance increases once they are loaded initially because by default events are cached.