# FullCalendar: Adding multiple events in-batch for higher performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Before I add this as a feature request, does anyone know of an effective way of adding events to a calendar that does not immediately invoke a render?

If what I am seeing is correct, the call to "renderEvent" in a loop will cause the calendar to re-render. I am trying to add hundreds of events dynamically (based on user action) and looking to improve performance.

I could envision something like:

```
.fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', [array of Events and Sticky attributes]);
```

or

```
.fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent, true, false);
.fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent2, true, false);
.fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent3, true, true);
```

Where a third parameter, "render" is a boolean letting the user skip the actual rendering process until they have added the last event.

Or am I mistaken and renderEvent is smarter / faster than I am giving it credit for?

-Brian

Comment: It looks like you might find an answer in http://stackoverflow.com/q/5950358

Comment: Yes this looks exactly what I was looking for! You should have posted a formal response so I could have marked you as answered. Do you want to?